# Understanding Mobile Redirect

Tags: redirect, mobile

I currently have access to the server where pvmcitypaper.com is hosted. However, I do not have access to the registrar to make DNS changes.

I have created a page directing users to the new site. However, when I attempt to access the page from mobile, I receive a "too many redirects" message. It seems to be redirecting to m.pvmcitypaper.com.

Any help you can offer to stop this redirect so if a user goes to the the site by mobile the will be at pvmcitypaper.com and not m.pvmcitypaper.com.

Thanks.